# $\lim _\limits{n\to \infty }\left(4n^2\left(\frac{n^3+3n^2+3}{2n^3+n-1}\right)^n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I calculate this limit?
$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty }\left(4n^2\left(\frac{n^3+3n^2+3}{2n^3+n-1}\right)^n\right)\:$
Can I apply the rule $a_n+1/a_n$ to proove its convergence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$a_n:=4n^2\left(\frac{n^3+3n^2+3}{2n^3+n-1}\right)^n=4n^2\left(\frac{1+3/n+3/n^3}{2+1/n^2-1/n^3}\right)^n.$$
Can we say that $a_n\sim\frac{4n^2}{2^n}$?

Comment: 4n^2/2^n tends to 0, right? Not the same limit as the one we get when we apply ^1/n, as suggested before.

Comment: @Maria That's right!

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: Try using this fact that $$\sqrt[n]{4n^2}\to1,~~\sqrt[n]{\left({\frac{n^3+3n^2+3}{2n^3+n-1}}\right)^n}\to 0.5$$ when $n\to\infty$ and so the corresponding series converges and so...